# Conditional Inline Styling with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is this sort of thing possible?

```
<Text style={{ opacity: ${ "blue" == "blue" ? 1 : 0 }, textAlign:"right" }}>Retry</Text>
```

I know this isn't HOW you do it because it isn't working. But was wondering if there was a way to conditionally create styling without creating an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need `${ }`, i.e.:

```
<Text style={{ opacity: "blue" == "blue" ? 1 : 0, textAlign:"right" }}>Retry</Text>
```

Or to make opacity completely optional you could do something like this:

```
<Text style={{ opacity: "blue" == "blue" ? 1 : null, textAlign:"right" }}>Retry</Text>
```